# VBA Json Parsing

Tags: json, vba, excel

I am trying to parse an Json response in Excel macro .

Below is the Json response

```
{
    "@ParentID": "111112594059",
    "@ID": "1C7E0A19",
    "@title": "1C7E0A19",
}
```

[image]

I am trying to extract value of @ParentID in the excel cell , but it is giving a type mismatch error. Can some one please help.

Comment: `= JSON("@ParentID")` ?

Comment: :) , It worked . Thanks a lot

Comment: @Slai how can we read an inner loop , like  "Values": {
        "Value": [
            {
                "@AttributeID": "9999",
                "@title": "Private Brand Check 2 Exit",
                "$": "2015-08-18 15:05:45"
            },
            {
                "AttributeID": "10041",
                "title": "No UPC Maintenance Changes Exit",
                "$": "2015-06-03 10:05:22"
            },    i want to read AttributeID value

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245469/4717755) helps.

Comment: Thanks, able to achive using JSON("Values")("Value")(1)("@AttributeID") code. Thanks,