# Adding to existing JSON from excel

Tags: json, vba, excel

I want to add to this JSON file in excel using vba.

So I have this JSON file

```
{
    "root": [{
        "STATUS_RESPONSE": {
            "STATUS": {
                "STATUS": {
                    "OWNER": "root"
                }
            },
            "REQ_ID": "00000",
            "RESULT": [{
                "USER": {
                    "BUSINESS_ID": "A",
                    "USER_NUMBER": "45",
                    "LANGUAGE": "F"
                }
            },
            {
                "USER_SESSION": {
                    "USER_ID": "0000001009",
                    "HELP_URL": "http://google.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "USER_ACCESS": {
                    "SERVICES_ROLE": "true",
                    "JOURNALLING": "true"

                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

I want to add another "USER" right below it so it looks like

```
{
    "root": [{
        "STATUS_RESPONSE": {
            "STATUS": {
                "STATUS": {
                    "OWNER": "root"
                }
            },
            "REQ_ID": "00000",
            "RESULT": [{
                "USER": {
                    "BUSINESS_ID": "A",
                    "USER_NUMBER": "45",
                    "LANGUAGE": "F"
                }
            },
            {     
                 "USER": {
                    "BUSINESS_ID": "B",
                    "USER_NUMBER": "55",
                    "LANGUAGE": "E"
                }
            },
            {
                "USER_SESSION": {
                    "USER_ID": "0000001009",
                    "HELP_URL": "http://google.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "USER_ACCESS": {
                    "SERVICES_ROLE": "true",
                    "JOURNALLING": "true"

                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

This is what I have currently

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim z As Integer, items As New Collection, myitem As New Dictionary
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Variant
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream
Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("test.json", ForReading)
JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close
Set JSON = ParseJson(JsonText)

Set rng = Range("A5")

z = 0
For Each cell In rng
    myitem("BUSINESS_ID") = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    myitem("USER_NUMBER") = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    myitem("LANGUAGE") = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
    items.Add myitem
    Set myitem = Nothing
z = z + 1
Next

myfile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test.json"
Open myfile For Output As #1
Print #1, ConvertToJson(myitem, Whitespace:=2)
MsgBox ("Exported to JSON file")
Close #1

End Sub
```

All this does is add it below the existing JSON and is not connected to it all.

How would I go about add another "USER" right below the current one with the information from excel

Comment: You create the parsed JSON object (which is what you need to modify), but then you do nothing with it.  Within that object "RESULT" is already an existing collection - so add each `myItem` to that.  And you can't set `myItem` to nothing if you loop over more than one row, or how will you add the next item?

Comment: How would I go about defining the existing collection

Comment: `Set items = JSON("root")(1)("STATUS_RESPONSE")("RESULT")`

Comment: A similar thing I did was just JSON("root")(1)("STATUS_RESPONSE")("RESULT").Add myItem which added it to the result object at the bottom

Comment: Also, any idea if there was like more keys and values inside that "USER" that I don't modify in the excel, how can I add them as well?

Comment: If you want to *modify* an existing user that's very different from adding a new one: you'd need to loop over the collection of USER objects and identify which one needed to be updated.

Comment: What I meant was let say my original user had two field below LANGUAGE called for instance, FNAME and LNAME, but I don't modify them in the excel, how can I transfer those two to the new object USER I just made below it

Comment: Have you considered putting all of the fields in excel?

Comment: I have, it would be easier that way but was wondering if there a way to do it without having too?

Comment: You already have the JSON object loaded, and you know how to access the existing keys, so read from the existing user object and add the keys and values to your new user.

Comment: You need to clone the collection by copying each element from original within loop, and inserting the new element at the necessary position, then assign new cloned object instead of original.

Comment: @TimWilliams how would I access the key, I know how to do values but for the key I can't figure it out

Comment: `For each k in JSON("root")(1)("STATUS_RESPONSE")("RESULT")(1)("USER"): debug.print k, JSON("root")(1)("STATUS_RESPONSE")("RESULT")(1)("USER")(k)`

Comment: That just gives me the values for each thing inside and not the keys

Comment: `k` is the key name and `[path_here](k)` is the value

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245469/4717755) to see if it helps