# Fetch data through an API call which requires credentials using Excel VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying the fetch data through an API call which requires credentials (API key and password).

I can do it through Python script. I would like to do it through Excel VBA because I want to download the data and formatting in same excel sheet in one click.

I have tried many things through VBA Excel after taking the help from many developer community websites.

Python code snippet -

```
import requests
import json

api_key = "NotLikeToMention1"
domain = "NotLikeToMention2"
password = "NotLikeToMention3"

r = requests.get("https://"+ domain +".freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?filter=new_and_my_open", auth = (api_key, password))

data = r.json()
print(data)
```

I tried the below code in Excel VBA. I also tried using authorization through `setRequestHeader` property. While using these ways, I get an error something like

> 'credential error, you will have to login'.

```vb
Dim response As String

With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  .Open "GET", address, false, emailId, password
  .Send
  response = .responseText
End With

Msgbox response
```

Comment: can you check the status error message? i'ts 401?

Comment: I'd recommend either doing all your work in Python, using an [Excel library](https://www.quora.com/What-python-libraries-are-best-for-working-with-Microsoft-Excel) or if you want to use VBA, use a [JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) and be mindful of [how the data is returned to the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245469/4717755).

Comment: @PeterT Yes, I will use Json parser, however as of now I am not able to get the Json string after calling API get request. I am struggling to find how to call a API link which requires credential.

Comment: @LuizLai I don't know how to check the status. If I am sign in at Freshdesk portal then I can directly open this url in browser and I can see the huge json string. Through python also I can see, but it I am trying to do it through VBA excel then I am getting error which is popping up through a error message window and title of that error message is "Microsoft Excel" and full error message is 

"{"code":"invalid_credentials","message":"You have to be logged in to perform this action.""

Comment: I'd keep your code in Python and wrap it a COM class that is callable from VBA http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/calling-python-class-using-vba-with-com.html

Comment: but if you insist it is probably missing HTTP headers.

Comment: Use Fiddler to compare the actual request from the Python script vs VBA code.

Comment: Use `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` instead of deprecated `Microsoft.XMLHTTP`. Also try `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`.

Comment: You probably need to Base64encode your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be an option for your problem.

There is a simple way to fectch data from API using Power Query, and formmating JSON into Excel files.

This is several great example

1. [Getting Started with API’s in Power Query](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/getting-started-with-apis-in-power-query)
2. [Power Query – Building functions to fetch web data](https://hatfullofdata.blog/power-query-fetch-web-data/)