# How to get all items in multiple Arrays in a JSON file using VBA?

Tags: arrays, json, excel, vba

Basically I want to read some .JSONn files with very structured data (many arrays, items and values) and my goal is to put the items and values in an excel sheet. I have trouble getting stuck when I reach arrays data-type.

I can read the files and include some items and values using the Library VBA-JSON 2.3.1

```
Dim jsonObject As Object, i As Integer, FSO

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("D:\JSON\file.json", ForReading)

JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll

JsonTS.Close

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText)

i = 2
n = 1

    For Each Item In jsonObject
        ws.Cells(i, n) = jsonObject(Item)
        i = i + 1: n = n + 1
    Next

    MsgBox ("Complete!")

Set jsonObject = Nothing
```

Here's my sructured JSON file:

```
{
  "id": "2ca5da11-b311-43db-9661-afa3b833aad4",
  "name": "_menuAposentacoes",
  "auto": true,
  "contexts": [],
  "responses": [
    {
      "resetContexts": false,
      "affectedContexts": [
        {
          "name": "aposentacoes_22-followup",
          "parameters": {},
          "lifespan": 2
        }
      ],
      "parameters": [
        {
          "id": "6e86b18e-77c1-4571-ad53-eba8db91d4b3",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@aposentacao",
          "name": "aposentacao",
          "value": "$aposentacao",
          "promptMessages": [],
          "noMatchPromptMessages": [],
          "noInputPromptMessages": [],
          "outputDialogContexts": [],
          "isList": true
        },
        {
          "id": "be28b756-32dd-40e7-99db-d7f91cc9ddb6",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@CGA",
          "name": "CGA",
          "value": "$CGA",
          "promptMessages": [],
          "noMatchPromptMessages": [],
          "noInputPromptMessages": [],
          "outputDialogContexts": [],
          "isList": false
        },
        {
          "id": "f52786f0-15cd-4fc4-983f-32b248ddcf3f",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@descontos",
          "name": "descontos",
          "value": "$descontos",
          "promptMessages": [],
          "noMatchPromptMessages": [],
          "noInputPromptMessages": [],
          "outputDialogContexts": [],
          "isList": false
        },
        {
          "id": "6e7f4c49-f35f-46fb-9db9-c24eb16f0b40",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@situacaoCGA",
          "name": "situacaoCGA",
          "value": "$situacaoCGA",
          "promptMessages": [],
          "noMatchPromptMessages": [],
          "noInputPromptMessages": [],
          "outputDialogContexts": [],
          "isList": false
        },
        {
          "id": "70328121-e748-4508-a287-7fc30a9cd9f6",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@penalizacao",
          "name": "penalizacao",
          "value": "$penalizacao",
          "promptMessages": [],
          "noMatchPromptMessages": [],
          "noInputPromptMessages": [],
          "outputDialogContexts": [],
          "isList": false
        }
      ],
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "lang": "pt",
          "speech": "Some text."
        },
        {
          "type": 4,
          "lang": "pt",
          "payload": {
            "message": "Some text: ",
            "ignoreTextResponse": false,
            "platform": "kommunicate",
            "metadata": {
              "contentType": "300",
              "templateId": "6",
              "payload": [
                {
                  "title": "Other text",
                  "message": "Other text"
                },
                {
                  "title": "Other text",
                  "message": "Other text"
                },
                {
                  "title": "Other text",
                  "message": "Other text"
                },
                {
                  "title": "Other text",
                  "message": "Other text"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": 4,
          "lang": "pt",
          "payload": {
            "message": "Other text",
            "ignoreTextResponse": false,
            "platform": "kommunicate",
            "metadata": {
              "contentType": "300",
              "templateId": "6",
              "payload": [
                {
                  "title": "Sim",
                  "message": "Sim"
                },
                {
                  "title": "Não",
                  "message": "Não"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "defaultResponsePlatforms": {},
      "speech": []
    }
  ],
  "priority": 500000,
  "webhookUsed": false,
  "webhookForSlotFilling": false,
  "fallbackIntent": false,
  "events": []
}
```

Comment: Is the structure regular across the files? Will you be writing files to the same sheet?

Comment: Yes QHarr, the structure is completely regular among the other files with, offcourse, different text and some or less items, but basically the structure is the same.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245469/4717755) where you can understand how the JSON object breaks down into different types of structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a useful routine that can help you determine how to parse the JSON data, based on information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245469/4717755). The routine is recursive, so it will successively call itself to continue parsing the JSON input.

The current output is to the immediate window using `Debug.Print`, but you can modify these statements to put the results into worksheet cells according to your needs and format (which was not really specified in your question).

Notice that the `level` parameter is incremented by two with each JSON level. This is likely due to the format of the JSON source itself. For example, the top-level `responses` field has both a `[` and a `{` to indicate internal structure. You can adjust the logic to deal with this however best suits your use case.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportJSON()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim jsonFilename As String
    Dim jsonFile As Object
    Dim jsonText As String
    jsonFilename = "D:\JSON\file.json"
    Set jsonFile = fso.OpenTextFile(Filename:=jsonFilename, IOMode:=ForReading)
    jsonText = jsonFile.ReadAll
    jsonFile.Close

    Dim json As Object
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)

    OutputJSON "(top)", json, 1
End Sub

Sub OutputJSON(ByVal itemName As String, _
               ByRef jsonItem As Variant, _
               ByVal level As Long)
    Dim item As Variant
    Select Case TypeName(jsonItem)
        Case "Dictionary"
            For Each item In jsonItem
                If IsObject(jsonItem(item)) Then
                    If jsonItem(item).Count = 0 Then
                        Debug.Print level & " " & itemName & "." & _
                                    item & " is empty " & _
                                    TypeName(jsonItem(item))
                    Else
                        OutputJSON itemName & "." & item, jsonItem(item), level + 1
                    End If
                Else
                    Debug.Print level & " " & itemName & "." & _
                                item & " = " & jsonItem(item)
                End If
            Next item

        Case "Collection"
            Dim i As Long
            i = 1
            For Each item In jsonItem
                If IsObject(item) Then
                    OutputJSON itemName & "[" & i & "]", item, level + 1
                Else
                    Debug.Print level & ": " & itemName & "[" & i & "]", item
                End If
                i = i + 1
            Next item
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Very appreciated PeterT! Modified plenty your line of code but was its structured that allowed me to pursue my main goal!