# Iteration from Json Format data to Ms Access Table

Tags: json, vba

I need to get the concept clear on how to get or referencing the data from Json formatinto VBA code that will eventually paste the same into Ms Access table. I have the API that provide the Json data but the problem is how to move it the ms access table or pasting it there.

**Json Code:**

```
{ 
“Tax”: “889633344”, 
“TaxpayerName”: “Nector”, 
“Addreess”: “westVell”, 
“DateTime”: “20190101203450”, 
“TerminalID”: “USDY95830005”, 
“InvoiceCode”: “KHTY58961803014”, 
“InvoiceNumber”: “000070001”, 
“FCVRCode”: “TYJK58YUIO03938000”, 
“TELEPHONENUMBER”: “+27869300361”, 
“Operator”: “NECTOR”, 
“TaxItems”: [ 
{ 
“TaxLabel”: “A”, 
“CategoryName”: “Standard Rate”, 
“Rate”: 0.16, 
“TaxAmount”: 28.98 
}, 
{ 
“TaxLabel”: “B”, 
“CategoryName”: “MTV”, 
“Rate”: 0.12, 
“TaxAmount”: 96.77 
} 
], 
“TotalAmount”: 309.12, 
“VerificationUrl”: “WWW.nector.info”
```

The above data need to be moved to the table Ms Access called ("tblEfdReceipts")

**VBA Code for receiving**

```
Private Sub StoreData(ADataObject As Object)
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim item As Object
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblEfdReceipts")
  For Each item In ADataObject
    rs.AddNew
            rs![TAX] = item("TAX")
            rs![TaxpayerName] = item("TaxpayerName")
            rs![Address] = item("Address")
            rs![DateTime] = item("DateTime")
            rs![TerminalID] = item("TerminalID")
            rs![InvoiceCode] = item("InvoiceCode")
            rs![InvoiceNumber] = item("InvoiceCode")
            rs![SpecialCode] = item("SpecialCode")
            rs![TelephoneNumber] = item("TelephoneNumber")
            rs![Operator] = item("Operator")
            rs![Taxlabel] = item("TaxItems")("TaxLabel")
            rs![CategoryName] = item("TaxItems")("CategoryName")
            rs![Rate] = item("TaxItems")("Rate")
            rs![TaxAmount] = item("TaxItems")("TaxAmount")
            rs![VerificationUrl] = item("TaxItems")("VerificationUrl")
            rs.Update
  Next item
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I do not know json code, does this come as a file or can there be multiple files?

Comment: Have a look to https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser. There are plenty of questions and answers on SO about the JSonParser.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245469/4717755) describes how the JSON Parser @FunThomas mentions creates a structure of objects based on the JSON data ingested. Knowing which collection/dictionary/array object to use, you can make the assignments as you indicate in your question.

Comment: Thank you Peter , this is okay with me