# Excel VBA code to parse and save API JSON data into excel table

Tags: json, excel, vba, api

I have below VBA code to fetch API data. I fetched the data successfully and also converted from JSON format to dictionary format by using JSON converted code. Now I am struggling to convert this dictionary format data into excel table.

```vb
Sub ReadFromAPI()

    ' Set the request from the API
    Dim request As New WinHttpRequest
    request.Open "GET", "https://api.com"
    
    ' Send the request
    request.Send
    
    ' Check the result
    If request.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox request.ResponseText
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Convert the response from JSON to a Dictionary structure
    Dim response As Object
    Set response = JsonConverter.ParseJson(request.ResponseText)
    
   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
   'VBA Code need to be added here to Access data  from dictionary format into Excel table
   ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

End Sub
```

value in Dictionary format in local variable(response)
[image: Out put received in Dictionary format]

sample of dictionary out put
[image: out put in dictionary format]

Output data need to be converted into below excel table

[image: Output table format]

Comment: `response` will be a Collection of Dictionary objects, so start by looping over that.

Comment: ...you're making it difficult for folks to spin up a working example by including the JSON as an image, instead of plain text which can be copied and pasted.

Comment: Study [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245469/4717755) to understand how the JSON converter parses the JSON into a structure of different objects. Then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60511987/4717755) gives an example of how you can set up a loop to run through the JSON data.