# Writing a file from object

Tags: excel, vba, object, readfile, writefile

I want to write a text file that contains all the data from within an object.
I know how to create and open a text file using vba, also how to write from a range or string going through every line but I have not found a solution for doing the same with an object.
Any help would be appreciated. The object in question is genereated by parsing a .json file into an object in vba and then selecting the necessary objects withing.

```
Public Sub exportobejct(obj)
    dim path as string
    dim filename as string
    dim filenumber as string

    path = "C:\Mypath\"
    filename = "myfilename"
    filenumber = Freefile
    Open filepath & filename for output as filenumber
'Here would be the code to write into the textfile, which I failed 
'What I tried:
    For r in obj.rows.cells.count-1
        for c in obj.columns.cells.count-1
            print filenumber, obj.cells(r,c)
'or
            print filenumber, obj.cells(1).offset(r,c).value
        next c
    next r
'sth else I tried:
    Print filenumber, obj
'or
    for each cc in obj.rows
        write filenumber, cc 
    next cc

    Close filenumber
End sub
```

> Ive seen there is also an option creating files using FSO see Link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba](https://stackoverflow.com)
>
> I still dont know how to write from an object however.
>
> Some additional information: The object that I want to write from may contain several more objects > within, if that poses any issues.

Comment: Don't you want to write the object out as JSON to the file? In this manner, the object can be recreated to/from JSON. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PeterT I am fairly new to vba, so maybe the question is super stupid. All I want is a textfile of all the things inside that object. I can open the json file with an editor and see whats inside but I do not know how I see whats inside the object variable that I imported parts of that json file.  I dont know how to export it.

Comment: What kind of object is your code producing? Is it a VBA class? There must be some kind of `Set obj = new ...` in the code: What is it? Where is it defined?

Comment: There is no built-in support for persisting a generic "object" to a file - you would need to provide a method which "serializes" the object into a form which can be written to a file (and from which you can then reconstitute the object at a later time). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/ (.NET but covers the basic concept)

Comment: Because you have a custom object, it's up to you to define how (what format) to write that object to a file. In general, writing it out as text (CSV, JSON, INI, etc) is perfectly acceptable - it's really up to you. Since you're already working with JSON, you may want to write your object to a JSON file. [Here is a handy reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245469/4717755) for how to map objects (or even compound objects) to JSON that might help.